# Internal name for Sharepoint Online column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, administration, internal-name

How do I get the internal name for columns in SharePoint Online? For example the "Created By" column is only the display name but I need the internal SharePoint name for this column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the internal column name by going the list settings where the column is used and then selecting the column. Once you are in the column settings page you can find the internal name in the url under the "Field" param.

[image: Url]

Answer (score 2):

You also could use PnP PowerShell to get the internal field name of all fields in a SharePoint Online list.

```
$SiteURL = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/test"
$ListName ="Projects"
 
Try {
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Interactive
     
    Get-PnPField -List $ListName
}
Catch {
    Write-host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor Red
}
```

===================================

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Comment: I’m checking how the things are going on about this issue. Whether the answer helps you? If there is any problem with this issue, feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Internal name of SharePoint default "Created By" column is **Author**.

There are multiple ways to get the internal name of your SharePoint column, via SharePoint UI, SharePoint REST API or PowerShell.

You can use endpoint like below to get the internal name using SharePoint REST API:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/SPConnect/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List Name')/fields?$select=Title,InternalName&$filter=Title eq 'Created By'
```

You can find other ways in this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)